# Formula for drawing a pixel at an X,Y coordinate on Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, 2d

So I am aware the HTML5 canvas pixel methods are a little different then normal. I am porting a ray-tracer from a Scala Swing application where the old draw method looked like this:

```
for {
  x <- pixels.s.indices
  y <- pixels.s(x).indices
} {
  g.setColor(pixels.s(x)(y))
  g.fillRect(x, y, x, y)
}
```

Where `pixels.s` was a 2D array like so:

```
[[Color, Color, Color], 
 [Color, Color, Color], 
 [Color, Color, Color]]
```

I.e. it mapped exactly to a 2D cartesian plane.

So now I have changed tack slightly, and I have a FLATTENED array of objects with `x`, `y` and `color`:

```
[{ x: 0, y: 0, color: { red: 33, green: 220, blue: 181 },
 { x: 0, y: 1, color: { red: 33, green: 220, blue: 231 },
 { x: 0, y: 2, color: { red: 33, green: 220, blue: 221 },
 ...
 { x: 319, y: 238, color: { red: 23, green: 10, blue: 31 },
 { x: 319, y: 239, color: { red: 13, green: 120, blue: 11 }]
```

I'm trying to draw my flattened array of colors to the screen using this code:

```
var imageData = context.createImageData(width, height);
var numPixels = width*height;
for (var i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
  imageData.data[(i*4)]     = tracedScene[i].color.red;
  imageData.data[(i*4) + 1] = tracedScene[i].color.green;
  imageData.data[(i*4) + 2] = tracedScene[i].color.blue;
  imageData.data[(i*4) + 3] = 255; // alpha  color
};
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

But it's coming out a bit wrong. I've tripled checked my tests and the actual array is the correct screen data. I'm just rendering it incorrectly. I'm currently getting this:

[image]

Whereas I should see:

[image]

Now I've had the exact same graphical oddities in the Swing version before (years ago), and it was because of the way I was drawing the image. I can't remember how I fixed it however.

What I am looking to be able to do, is have some method:

```
drawPixel(x, y, color, canvas) { ... }
```

that is able to draw a particular pixel at x, y with a color. OR... a way to do it traditionally.

Comment: http://beej.us/blog/data/html5s-canvas-2-pixel/

Comment: Can you post how you use the `imageData` to draw and/or what do you expect to be shown on the image?

Comment: Yep Ill post an image of what I should see. I've edited the post with the imageData bit. It's the canvas object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input "flattened" array in wrong order: it should be by rows, but yours is by columns.

```
[{ x: 0, y: 0, color: { red: 33, green: 220, blue: 181 },
 { x: 1, y: 0, color: { red: 33, green: 220, blue: 231 },
 { x: 2, y: 0, color: { red: 33, green: 220, blue: 221 },
 ...
```

(Assuming y is top to bottom, x - left to right)

Comment: Thank you. This solved my issue. I thought canvas was by rows, not columns.

Answer (score 1):

Image data goes from `(0, 0)` to `(1, 0)` and your code goes from `(0, 0)` to `(0, 1)`. In other words, there's a conflict of row/column major order.

Anyway, depending on your performance needs you might be overthinking this.

> What I am looking to be able to do, is have some method:
>
> `drawPixel(x, y, color, canvas) { ... }`
>
> that is able to draw a particular pixel at x, y with a color.

Why not just fill single pixels?

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)';
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
```

**This will be inefficient at around 100 pixels filled, and you'll want to switch to image data.**

If you want to keep your data structure the same you could use something like this, which should work:

```
var imageData = context.createImageData(width, height);
var numPixels = width*height;
var pixelCount = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        var wpixel = j * width * 4;
        wpixel += i * 4;
        console.log(wpixel);
        imageData.data[(wpixel)]     = tracedScene[pixelCount].red;
        imageData.data[(wpixel) + 1] = tracedScene[pixelCount].green;
        imageData.data[(wpixel) + 2] = tracedScene[pixelCount].blue;
        imageData.data[(wpixel) + 3] = 255; // alpha  color
        pixelCount++; // independent of i and j the way I wrote it
    }
}
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t9edv/

Comment: Well given it's an image of width * height (where width and height will be around 640x480, and thus 307200 pixels), I think I might need image data.

Comment: I changed your image data code to work in column major order if you don't feel like reordering your data. (added to answer)

Comment: Thanks. Mine was a 1 line change in my tracing code, but this might be useful for others.